# How do I replace a match with the found regex case insensitive, but extend the result

Tags: javascript

Simply, I have the string: `Hello and good morning world.` and
I have a search string: `Good`.

I want to match everything that has the search string case insensitive, but I need the result to extend it like:

`Hello and <mark>good</mark> morning world.`

I am still doing some research, but it looks more complicated then I thought. I hope you can help. I couldn't find any kind of thread so far. Hopefully you can point me to one or even solve this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `string.replace(/(Good)/i, '<mark>$1</mark>')` how about this.

Comment: Wow, you are a god, it works perfectly. But how does it working with the case insensitive? Can you make a short explanation?

Comment: you can specify `i` in last to ignore the case. also `g` for global, if multiple `good` words are there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the expected result, using `replace` function of string by specifying the ignore and global case in the regex:

```js
var string = 'Hello and good morning world.';

var result = string.replace(/(Good)/ig, '<mark>$1</mark>');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You saved my day. Will mark it later as correct answer